# What is the variable scope for async tasks?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
var itemIds, result, taskQueue, _i, _len;
itemIds = [];
taskQueue = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
  console.log('Hello ' + task.name);
  return callback();
}, 10);
for (_i = 0, _len = results.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  result = results[_i];
  taskQueue.push({}, function(err) {
    var item;
    item = new Item(result);
    return item.save(function(err, new_item) {
      itemIds[itemIds.length] = new_item._id;
      console.log(new_item._id);
      return console.log(itemIds);
    });
  });
}
taskQueue.drain = function() {
  console.log('Queue Done!');
  return console.log(itemIds.length);
};
```

is my code. But itemIds shows as empty when the `drain` is run. This is using the `async` module for `node.js` by the way

Comment: Sounds like your using `async.queue` wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally recommend you heavily simplify the code using [after](https://github.com/Raynos/after.js)

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

var cb = after(results.length, function() {
    var items = slice.call(arguments);
    console.log("All done");
    console.log(items.length);
});

results.forEach(function(result) {
    item = new Item(result);
    item.save(function(err, newItem) {
        cb(newItem);   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Nice!  I'm not a fan of having to specify the # of tasks up front though.  That seems a bit limiting.  Obviously not an issue in this case, but generally I'd prefer to have a way to add tasks to the cb object after the fact.  Does After support that?

Comment: @broofa nope. After runs after a static number of requests. the idea is that it's bad design to want to wait for N tasks where N is undetermined. I've never needed to wait on N tasks where I don't know N. By all means give me an example and i'll refactor it to work with after

Comment: In an earlier question he asked about potentially trying to batch 1k db manipulations I recommend async. He could also use async.whilst and async.until. async.queue is useful if the tasks can be running concurrently. I think the bigger question is why is he trying to so many manipulations with Node.

Comment: The `after` link is 404 now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't variable scope, it's that async.queue doesn't know about all the async functions you're scheduling.  Specifically, it doesn't know about the item.save() calls - it only knows about the outer function that *schedules* item.save().  The actual save and resulting callback invocation are done asynchronously, after drain() has been called, which is why itemIds appears empty.  (Make sense?)

To solve this, I would suggest you use the [Step module](https://github.com/creationix/step) instead of `async`.  Specifically, look at Step's `group()` feature, which allows you to indicate when nested asynchronous control flows like this have finished.